# How to use nginx and docker to redirect all requests to new path?

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using nginx and docker to host an application, the conf file is:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  root /www/data;

  location /static {
    alias /var/www/static;
  }

  location /media {
    alias /var/www/media;
  }

  location ~* ^/(api|admin) {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://django:8000;
  }

  location /gateway {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
  }
```

and then we want to all the calls redirect to the new path instead of subdomain.
Like before the domain is something like sub.example.com, but we need to make it like www.example.com/sub. I try to change the server_name,but it doesn't work.

Comment: This config is for `sub.example.com` or what?

Comment: Yes, it's for subdomain--sub.exmaple.com

Comment: You will need to adjust this in your django app and nodejs app also if they render html. Because the static file and assets location will get a additional `/sub` in the url